# Handling board game fields with a loop?

Tags: java, android

This is my first question here. I am writing a simple game on Android (my first one). It is a board game with 64 fields. Now every time one field is clicked something needs to be done. I figured a way to do it in this way:

```
switch(v.getId()) {
case R.id.field1:
...
...
...
}
```

It is working but it is kind of annoying for 64 fields. Can I somehow retrieve fields IDs and do it in a loop?

```
findViewById(R.id.field+i).doSomething();
```

I know it cannot be done this way, I just want to ilustrate my thinking. The following would go in Javascipt but how to do it in Java? Is it possible?

Comment: you have the view already so you could write `v.doSomething()` or am I missing something here?

Comment: Henry, the thing is doSomething() is a method of my activity class, v is just a View object. Or am I missing something here and it can be somehow done? :)

Comment: `findViewById` gives you back a view therefore I thought that `doSomething` is implemented on the view.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no way to do this using the Android layout editor in Eclipse. The easiest way is to create the views programmatically and store them in a collection or an array:

```
TextView[] fields = new TextView[64];
for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
    TextView textView = new TextView(context);
    textView.setText("Programmatic TextView");
    parentLayout.addView(textView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    fields[i] = textView;
}
```

You can create the parentLayout view in the layout editor.

Comment: The idea with an array seems very interesting. I'll try that and see how it goes! Thank You :)

BTW. Can anyone briefly explain to me what is this context thing? So far I've only seen people writing "this" there. Does it matter? How?

Comment: Well, but how to give IDs to particular fields? I have a board game with 64 fields which I created with TableRows and LinearLayouts. Now I would like to give every LinearLayout (single field) and ID so that I could later perform some operations once a field is clicked.

Comment: An activity is an implementation of Context, or you can use parentLayout.getContext(). If you need to you can set any ID you want using textView.setId(...). However, IDs are usually only useful to find components and store a reference to them in a variable. You already have this with the fields array so you should not really need them.